# Which Broadcast Intent is sent when Android device/OS is started?

Tags: android, android-intent, startup, broadcast

And which Intent filter to use for monitoring this event respectively?

Answer (score 1):

You have:  [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
         </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

BootReceiver is your broadcastrecevicer class

and permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link from developer docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.